# PHP: Get CPU usage of ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick

Tags: php, benchmarking

In PHP, is there a way I can capture what the CPU usage is of each ImagaMagick/GraphicsMagick method I execute? Memory usage would be nice, too.

Basically, I'm trying to benchmark how much resources each library uses in my application.

Failed attempt:

```
exec('convert a.jpg a.png');

$result = array();

// Loop until process is detected
do
{
    exec('ps -eo comm,%cpu,%mem | grep ' . "convert", $result);
}
while($result === array());

// Display the changing CPU and memory usage of the process
do
{
    print_r($result);
    exec('ps -eo comm,%cpu,%mem | grep ' . "convert", $result);
}
while($result !== array());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory usage should be a matter of recording the output of `memory_get_usage(true)` and `memory_get_peak_usage(true)` before and after each call you want to measure, then subtracting them.

CPU usage I'm not sure about. On unix systems it could involve doing `exec()` to get the output of `ps -ef | grep $phpPid`, then parsing that. You can get `$phpPid = getmypid();`

Comment: How do I get the PID of the convert process (the library I call from PHP via exec())? That's the CPU usage I am interested in, I think.

Comment: If it's the php process itself, then `getmypid()` will give you its process id. If it's a separate library, find its binary executable name and `grep` for that: `ps -ef | grep $binaryName`.

Comment: ps -ef wasn't giving me what I needed, but ps -eo comm,%cpu,%mem was. Attempting to follow your suggestion, I've created a script that still doesn't work for me. My original post has been edited to show you what I did. Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. `exec()` will wait until convert has completed, so you won't see that process in `ps` afterwards. A possible solution in this case would be to have your script A launch a separate script B right before the `exec()`. Script B can do the checking of `ps` like you're doing, and report to some shared space (eg a file) the results.